# pyinstaller permission denied: C:\Python\Scripts\build

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm getting this error when I try to build my python script to exe file.
This is my script:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tkinter.messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title('BTCLoot - Loot BTC from your home!')
logoutButton = Button(root, text='Logout')
logoutButton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
balance = Label(text='Balance: N/A Sat.')
balance.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
root.geometry('600x250')
root.mainloop()
```

and this is what I get in console:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pyinstaller btcloot.py build
109 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3
109 INFO: Python: 3.6.2
109 INFO: Platform: Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
109 INFO: wrote C:\Python34\Scripts\btcloot.spec
109 INFO: UPX is not available.
109 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Python34\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts']
109 INFO: checking Analysis
109 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
109 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
109 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
125 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5109 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5109 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies o
inal executable
  required by c:\python34\python.exe
6093 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6109 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python34\Scripts\btcloot.py
6328 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python34\Scripts\build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.3', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 92, in r
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in r
build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_bui
))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
213, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", li
161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
415, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 2
 in run_script
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname, caller=caller)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph
", line 1326, in run_script
    with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\build'

C:\Python34\Scripts>pyinstaller btcloot.py build
103 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3
104 INFO: Python: 3.6.2
104 INFO: Platform: Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
106 INFO: wrote C:\Python34\Scripts\btcloot.spec
107 INFO: UPX is not available.
109 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Python34\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts']
110 INFO: checking Analysis
110 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
110 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
113 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
116 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5156 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5156 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies o
inal executable
  required by c:\python34\python.exe
6156 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6171 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python34\Scripts\btcloot.py
6406 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python34\Scripts\build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.3', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 92, in r
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in r
build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_bui
))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
213, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", li
161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", li
415, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 2
 in run_script
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(pathname, caller=caller)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph
", line 1326, in run_script
    with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\build'
```

Can someone help me? I'm new to `pyinstaller`.
Also, when I try to use `py2exe`, it does not compile it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it:

```
pyinstaller -F btcloot.py
```